# How to save ImageView Drawable State?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.android

I want to save my LED_F1 state which is an ImageView,On a certain condition I'm  changing the drawable image to another Led color .My Question is How do I save LED_F1 drawable image ? Thanks

```
public void LightOn_Drawable_Change()
    {
        LED_F1.SetBackgroundResource(Resource.Drawable.LEDGreen_F1);
        //Add Preferences
        var LED_F1_State = Application.Context.GetSharedPreferences("LED_F1 State",FileCreationMode.Private);
        var LED_F1_Editable = LED_F1_State.Edit();
        //LED_F1_Editable.PutInt("owais",LED_F1.Drawable.GetState); //What should I do here ? 
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to save the resource id with your `SharedPreferences`.

```
public void LightOn_Drawable_Change()
{
    LED_F1.SetBackgroundResource(Resource.Drawable.LEDGreen_F1);
    //Add Preferences
    var LED_F1_State = Application.Context.GetSharedPreferences("LED_F1 State",FileCreationMode.Private);
    var LED_F1_Editable = LED_F1_State.Edit();
    LED_F1_Editable.PutInt("On",Resource.Drawable.LEDGreen_F1); 
    LED_F1_Editable.Commit();
}
```

**Update**

You should use the same key when you save and when you get,and get the same SharedPreferences .

```
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
    // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
    SetContentView(Resource.Layout.activity_main);

   //---------------- Define Views --------------------

   // Getting my last LED state here !!!!!

    var LED_F1_State_Retrieve = Application.Context.GetSharedPreferences("Light On",FileCreationMode.Private);
    int LEDF1 = LED_F1_State_Retrieve.GetInt("Light On",0);
    var LED_F1_State_Retrieve = Application.Context.GetSharedPreferences("LED_F1 State",FileCreationMode.Private);
    int LEDF1 = LED_F1_State_Retrieve.GetInt("On",0);
    LED_F1.SetBackgroundResource(Resource.Drawable.LEDGreen_F1);
  }
```

Comment: Okay so saved this and restart my App , I don't get the saved state ? I believe I have to reinitialize it in OnCreate ?

Comment: @OwaisAhmed where do you save the data and how do you get it ?Could you show the codes ?